# ljust on str(row) has no outcome

Tags: python, debugging

Basically, I am developing a game, imagine it as 3D tick tack toe, you have a 3x3 grid where you can stack in hight as well. 
*upper* is basically the top view of every of these stacks.

**I want to line up a table properly, filling out the space with spaces.
However, ljust doesn't seem to work and I don't see the problem.**

Also, how do I make it that **None** is also properly aligned? 
Do I have to say *ljust(n+2)* and do an if statement before or is there an other way? 
Maybe a better approach in general?

Doing it on row directly (row.ljust(6)) gives me *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ljust'* 
Changing the value (20 instead of 6) doesn't change anything
rjust(); center() also don't work
It works on other strings, just like the center string above

```
#print out upper
print("0".center(10)+"1".center(10)+"2".center(10))
for count, row in enumerate(upper):
  print(count,str(row).ljust(10))



  Expected:
     0         1         2     
0 ['Green ', 'Blue  ', 'Purple']
1 ['Red   ', 'Red   ', 'Red   ']
2 [None    , None    , None    ]



Got:

    0         1         2     
0 ['Green', 'Blue', 'Purple']
1 ['Red', 'Red', 'Red']
2 [None, None, None]
```

Sry, didn't saw an other way to properly display outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to justify the elements of each row separately. You can do something similar for the heading to get everything lined-up properly.

```
upper = [
    ['Green', 'Blue', 'Purple'],
    ['Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
    [None, None, None]
]

#print out upper
print('    ' + '  '.join(repr(i).ljust(10) for i in range(3)))
for count, row in enumerate(upper):
    print(count, '[' + ', '.join(repr(elem).ljust(10) for elem in row) +']')
```

Output:

```
    0           1           2         
0 ['Green'   , 'Blue'    , 'Purple'  ]
1 ['Red'     , 'Red'     , 'Red'     ]
2 [None      , None      , None      ]
```